# Create Amazon Cloudfront distribution in a script (Windows)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is there anywhere a decent full example of creating a distribution (ideally with more than one origin - S3 and an AMS) from the command line?  I was a bit dismayed to find that it isn't a case of **"aws cloudfront blah blah..."**

In Windows, assuming no special tools - though any solution that needs a standalone exe is fine. I have been hinted to use cURL... but can't figure out all the stuff I need to pass in, or indeed how to use cURL to do so - have found it has a -h param for headers...but never used cURL so a bit lost.

Looked http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/CreateDistribution.html but am bemused by the sketchiness of the 'example'  e.g.

```
     POST /2013-09-27/distribution HTTP/1.1
     Host: cloudfront.amazonaws.com
     Authorization: AWS authentication string
     Date: Thu, 17 May 2012 19:37:58 GMT
     Other required headers
     ...
```

Where do I find my AWS authentication string?
What are the "Other required headers"
Distribution ID I can find on the Cloudfront admin page on the web

I am totally lost - need the real beginners guide here, step by step, ideally cross referenced to the Cloudfront admin page on the web. I'm a C#/SQL desktop apps dev normally, so this is way out of comfort zone.

Comment: looking now at the .net sdk... seems overkill, but hey gotta get the job done...

Comment: Authorization is the only required header. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html for what it should be. Which is somewhat complex...

Answer (score 0):

Have ended up using the [Amazon SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it probably **is** a matter of `aws cloudfront blah blah`
When typing `aws cloudfront` in a recent version of the AWS CLI one gets:

```
This service is only available as a preview service.

However, if you'd like to use a basic set of cloudfront commands with the
AWS CLI, you can enable this service by adding the following to your CLI
config file:

  [preview]
  cloudfront=true
```

Following this advice, you get the command `aws cloudfront create-distribution`.
I am personally still struggling to find the correct input for required params like `--distribution-config`

Comment: ah, maybe they've produced a "cloudfront" exe/script like the other since I made this query. It didn't exist back then.

Answer (score 0):

Running aws configure set preview.cloudfront true did not work for me. In my case (Linux), the following worked: 
Edit the file ~/.aws/config and add the content

```
 [preview]
 cloudfront=true
```

To its end. This [topic](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=162828) helped, but not mentioned the [brackets].